# PySpark Dataframe identify distinct value on one column based on duplicate values in other columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe like: where c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6 are the columns

> ```
>    +----------------------------+   
>    |c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 | c6 |  
>    |----------------------------|   
>    | a |  x |  y |  z |  g |  h |    
>    | b |  m |  f |  l |  n |  o |    
>    | c |  x |  y |  z |  g |  h |    
>    | d |  m |  f |  l |  n |  o |    
>    | e |  x |  y |  z |  g |  i |   
>    +----------------------------+
> ```

I want to extract c1 values for the rows which have same c2,c3,c4,c5 values but different c1 values.
Like, 1st, 3rd & 5th rows have same values for c2,c3,c4 & c5 but different c1 value. So the output should be **a, c & e**.
**(update)**
similarly, 2nd & 4th rows have same values for c2,c3,c4 & c5 but different c1 value. So the output should also contain **b & d**

How can I obtain such result ? I have tried applying groupby but I don't understand how to obtain distinct values for c1.

**UPDATE:**

Output should be a Dataframe of c1 values

```
# +-------+
# |c1_dups|
# +-------+
# |  a,c,e|
# |    b,e|
# +-------+
```

**My Approach:**

```
m = data.groupBy('c2','c3','c4','c5)
```

but I'm not understanding how to retrieve the values in m. I'm new to pyspark dataframes hence very much confused

Comment: It's a little bit hard to understand your issue. Can you write the output dataframe example?

Comment: Thanks :) Please check my update

Comment: can you update with group by approach that you have tried ?

Comment: It's a minimal approach. but yeah, updated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually very simple, let's create some data first :

```
schema = ['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6']

rdd = sc.parallelize(["a,x,y,z,g,h","b,x,y,z,l,h","c,x,y,z,g,h","d,x,f,y,g,i","e,x,y,z,g,i"]) \
        .map(lambda x : x.split(","))

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd,schema)
# +---+---+---+---+---+---+
# | c1| c2| c3| c4| c5| c6|
# +---+---+---+---+---+---+
# |  a|  x|  y|  z|  g|  h|
# |  b|  x|  y|  z|  l|  h|
# |  c|  x|  y|  z|  g|  h|
# |  d|  x|  f|  y|  g|  i|
# |  e|  x|  y|  z|  g|  i|
# +---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Now the fun part, you'll just need to import some functions, group by and explode as following :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

dupes = df.groupBy('c2','c3','c4','c5') \ 
          .agg(collect_list('c1').alias("c1s"),count('c1').alias("count")) \ # we collect as list and count at the same time
          .filter(col('count') > 1) # we filter dupes

df2 = dupes.select(explode("c1s").alias("c1_dups"))

df2.show()
# +-------+
# |c1_dups|
# +-------+
# |      a|
# |      c|
# |      e|
# +-------+
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: But what if I have multiple such duplicates, Check the question for my edit in desired output

Comment: I believe that you should ask a follow up question instead of the edit. It will be a mess otherwise.